# Python3: Remove array elements with same coordinate (x,y)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have this array (x,y,f(x,y)):

```
a=np.array([[ 1,  5,  3],
   [ 4,  5,  6],
   [ 4,  5, 6.1],
   [ 1,  3, 42]])
```

I want to remove the duplicates with same x,y.  In my array I have (4,5,6) and (4,5,6.1) and I want to remove one of them (no criterion).

If I had 2 columns (x,y) I could use

```
np.unique(a[:,:2], axis = 0)
```

But my array has 3 columns and I don't see how to do this in a simple way.
I can do a loop but my arrays can be very large.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: please give us an  example of your 3-D input and desired output. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need this:

```
a[np.unique(a[:,:2],axis=0,return_index=True)[1]]
```

output:

```
[[ 1.  3. 42.]
 [ 1.  5.  3.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]]
```

Please be mindful that it does not keep the original order of rows in `a`. If you want to keep the order, simply sort the indices:

```
a[np.sort(np.unique(a[:,:2],axis=0,return_index=True)[1])]
```

output:

```
[[ 1.  5.  3.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]
 [ 1.  3. 42.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this?

- np.rint will round your numbers to an integer

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
   [ 1,  5,  3],
   [ 4,  5,  6],
   [ 4,  5, 6.1],
   [ 1,  3, 42]
   ])

a = np.unique(np.rint(a), axis = 0) 

print(a)

//result :
[[ 1.  3. 42.]
 [ 1.  5.  3.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]]
```

Comment: This is a good way but, is it possible to recover their previous values (before doing the rounding) after removing the duplicate?

Comment: you can do  `b  = np.unique(np.rint(a), axis = 0) ` that way your original array will not be overwritten. But why? 
If you have a bunch of coordinates I wouldn't use `np.rint` at all and just go with the `np.unique` function

Comment: Yes, I can do that then you have to update the values of b somehow. I want the final result without rounded values. 
But without `np.rint` I can't remove duplicates with same x and y.

Comment: Pass `return_index=True` to get the indexes and use those to slice `a`.

Comment: @QuangHoang could  you please elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: `_, idx = np.unique(np.rint(a), axis=0, return_index=True); b=a[idx].copy()`.